# Webpay for CA tax return not allowed owing to absence of previous records

Tags: united-states, california, state-taxes

I want to pay to CA state through web pay my tax due for 2020, but I am not allowed to register because I don't have a previous tax return. I am filing as non-resident alien. How can I make this payment?

Answer (score 2):

Following a link on the web pay site for [Help with bank account payments](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/pay/bank-account/help-with-bank-account-payments.html), there is this FAQ:

> **If you never filed a California personal income tax return and owe tax**
>
> You must contact us for help. Have your California Driver License or
> California ID number available. You will not get to use some Web Pay
> features until you’ve filed a tax return.

The "contact us" link just sends you to a generic [Help website](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/help/index.html) where I assume you need to try to call or chat with FTB agents.

I wondered if you could sign up for a myFTB account but it also appears to require a previous tax return.